# subscribe to the newsletter not working

Tags: magento2, newsletter, subscription

I have a problem with magento 2.1.7, every time a guest user subscribe to the newsletter he doesn't receive confirmation email. I have already check on

> Configuration > Customer > Newsletter
>
> Configuration > Advanced > Admin

and check the cron job as well.
everything is fine but no resolution.

please help.

Comment: Thanks Kishan Savaliya, I debug for 2 days and at last I found this one.
It is exactly what my problem is and after set "Magento always manage emails" to Yes, my newsletter email start send out normally.

Answer (score 0):

There is one condition in Newsletter Email's Model file here..

> vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

```
if ($this->getImportMode()) {
    return $this;
}
```

If in this function you will get `true` as an Import Mode then these all functions will not work for newsletter emails.

- sendConfirmationRequestEmail()
- sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()
- sendUnsubscriptionEmail()

If you are using MailChimp for emails then you will get this issue, Because there is one setting available in MailChimp Configuration.

> Store > Configuration > MAILCHIMP > Mailchimp > Mailchimp General Configuration > Magento always manage emails

- In this setting you need to select "**Yes**", Because if you will select "**No**" there then Mailchimp will use **Import Mode** is **Yes**. So from Magento Customer will not get any newsletter emails.
- You can run below command to enable that setting without changing that in configuration.

```
php bin/magento config:set mailchimp/general/magentoemail 1
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!